# Пауза и работа SKAction

Tags: swift, spritekit

Приветствую!
Ставлю игрушку на паузу при помощи

```
self.scene?.paused = true
```

Данный метод прекращает работу всех экшенов на сцене. Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы некоторые экшены на сцене продолжали свою работу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

У вашей `SKScene` есть свойство `children`, это список всех `SKNode`, которые есть у сцены. берите оттуда какие вам надо и уже им делайте paused